# Input values from view not being binded correctly while hidden values are being bound with no problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building a forgot password feature in my project, where a user enters their email into a form and they get sent an email with a link to a page that allows them to reset their password.

When the form is submitted in the `ResetPassword` view below, only the hidden values `Token` and `Email` get bound correctly, while `Password` and `ConfirmPassword` come up as null. I have tried using `[FromForm]` too but when I do, all of the values come up as null as well. Am I missing something in terms of binding these values?

`ResetPassword` view:

```
@using IssueTracker.Models
@model ResetPassword

<h2>Reset Password</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input asp-for="Token" type="hidden" />
            <input asp-for="Email" type="hidden" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`ResetPassword` action method:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPassword model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model.Token, model.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return View("ResetConfirmation");
                    }
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                    }
                    return View(model);
                }
                return View("ResetConfirmation");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

`ResetPassword` model class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace IssueTracker.Models
{
    public class ResetPassword
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password and Confirm Password must match")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string Token { get; set; }

        public ResetPassword()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you check the spelling of the `Password` and `ConfirmPassword` fields in the ResetPassword model? Is the spelling is correct as you write in the input fields?

Comment: @Nayem_43 I provided the ResetPassword model above. The spelling is the same.

Comment: @MPagan, can this solve your problem? [asp-for inputs not binding to ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39478774/8795884)

Comment: @tontonsevilla I added a viewimports and it still doesn't work

Comment: @MPagan, make sure the your _ViewImports is under Views folder and not under the Shared folder. If still not working. Can you also include screenshot of your Solution Explorer showing with Views folder showing all the files in it and what is inside of your _ViewImports.cshtml

Comment: @tontonsevilla it works now thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the html helper?

`@Html.HiddenFor(x => @Model.Token);`

For further info check out https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/html-helpers

Comment: My hidden values are being binded correctly already with `type="hidden"` so that is not the issue. The binding of the other two values (password and confirmpassword) is the issue.